# compiler error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

```
#include <string>
...
template <typename DefinitionsIterator>
void parse(const CIET_NS ::VariadicArguments& argumentList, DefinitionsIterator firstDef, DefinitionsIterator lastDef, Map& res)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argumentList.size(); ++i) {
        CIET_NS ::Object obj = argumentList.at(i);
        std::string objStr = obj.convert<std::string>();
        qDebug() << objStr.c_str();

        //qDebug() << argumentList.at(i).convert<std::string>().c_str();

    }
```

This code compiles but the line commented doesn't. I am getting this error

```
 error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
```

How this could be happening?

```
template <typename ChildClass, typename ListElementType, typename DuplicateType>
class BasicObject
{
public:
    BasicObject();
    ~BasicObject();

public:
    Tcl_Obj* tclObject() const;
    Tcl_Obj* releaseObject();
    template <typename T>
    T convert(Interpreter& interp) const;
    template <typename T>
    T convert() const;
```

`Object` is derived from `BasicObject`

```
Compiler version:
g++ -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)
```

Comment: you guys don't do `using std;`?

Comment: @wheaties Naah. Sometimes, `using namespace std;` though.

Comment: @MrLister pfft, it's been almost 3 yrs since I wrote C++ :P

Comment: What compiler is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `convert` is a template, you have to indicate that (similar to using `typename` to indicate that a name is  a type).

```
qDebug() << argumentList.at(i).template convert<std::string>().c_str();
                               ^^^^^^^^
```

otherwise the compiler believes that `<` is a comparison and gets confused when seeing `>` before something that can be compared.

Comment: But why does it compile in three lines?

Comment: It's hard to explain (even if we know all the types involved). When doing it separately, the compiler knows the type of `obj` and that this type contains templates. When you do it all at once, the compiler isn't required to figure that out. The expression `a.at(i).c<x` just *could* be a comparison between `c` and `x`.

Comment: @BoPersson : which is why the C++'s grammar is not context-free. I'm really not convinced that you need to add ``template`` in there -- it will be interesting to know which compilers work and which don't work here. Of course, if it's some ancient VS, the OP has to do what he has to do...

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is ancient -- based on the data you provided, it is GCC 3.4.6 which shipped with RHEL4, which got EOLed by the vendor years ago (yes, now it's on an "extended life cycle" until 2015, which means that you are really, really not supposed to be deploying new applications on that).

The oldest GCC version which is supposed to work with any supported version of Qt is GCC 4.2 (under special circumstances) and GCC 4.4 (for Qt 4.7). Your compiler has a bug. Why do you need to deploy on such an archaic platform which canot compile a valid C++ code?